# Aggregate rows based on two identifiers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have the following data set

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['E1', 'E1', 'E1', 'E2', 'E2'],
                   'B' : ['R1', 'R1', 'R2', 'R2', 'R2'],
                   'C' : [100, 100, 300, 250, 250]})
```

I now want to aggregate the rows using `A` and `B` as the shared identifier for an observation. I then want to calculate the sum and the average of `C` and count the number of times this pair has been observed and append those values to a data frame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['E1', 'E1', 'E2'],
                   'B' : ['R1', 'R2', 'R2'],
                   'C_sum' : [200, 300, 500],
                   'C_avg' : [100, 300, 250],
                   'count' : [2, 1, 2]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `groupby` with `agg`

```
df.groupby(['A','B']).C.agg(['sum','mean','count']).reset_index()
A  B   sum  mean  count                  
E1 R1  200   100      2
E2 R2  300   300      1
E2 R2  500   250      2
```

Comment: Almost perfect! However, using this the  `E1` in the second row disappears which is crucial for me.

Comment: @PCK1992 check `df.groupby(['A','B']).C.agg(['sum','mean','count']).reset_index()`

Comment: Perfect, works as I want it to! Can you perhaps update your answer?

Comment: @PCK1992 sorry just edit , adding reset_index at the end